# How 2 user can work on 1 repository on GitHub

Tags: github

I am newbie in GitHub, before i was using SVN for development of visual studio project between users.

But question is how 2 users can work on one file of project with github?(in SVN one can lock that file and make change and commit after that).

So how development team can work on project on github? OR Which should be the best way to use github in team?

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties in understanding?

Comment: any locking mechanism as like SVN or user have their own copy of repository and after that how they can merge changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you checkout your copy of the repo on GitHub. You work with it and commit it. Your friend has his own "branch".

You want to prevent that he is working on the same file like you and you don't get conflicts after committing, right? I cant answer you directly since I'm also quite new to Git  but maybe this helps you:

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: branch option taking me to right direction however very difficult to understand from above link as beginner.

Comment: Check out the official documentation. Here's a basic crashcourse in Git for SVN users -> http://git-scm.com/course/svn.html also the official tutorial http://schacon.github.com/git/gittutorial.html :) The inventer of git, i forgot the name (i think it was the gnu men) also talks about it on youtube.